# How to check if all contents of an array pass a certain requirement

Tags: java, arrays

I have an assignment that asks to print all palindromic numbers between 10 and 10,000 whose proper divisors are also palindromic. So far I have been able to print all palindromic numbers and all of their divisors that are palindromic. But I have not been able to find a way to print only those palindromic numbers that have all of its proper divisors that are also palindromic

Attached is a link to the assingment so that you may understand what it is that I am asking/needing to do: http://azfoo.net/gdt/csc205/assignments/palindrome.html

**Specification**

Write a Java application that prints all of non-prime (i.e. composite) palindromic numbers between 10 and 10,000 that have all palindromic proper divisors.

Example: The number 3993 is a palindromic composite and all of the proper divisors of 3993 (1,3,11,33,121,363,1331) are palindromic.

Print one number per line. Each line should include a comma separated list of the proper divisors in parenthesis. Example output.

```
   22 (1,2,11)
   33 (1,3,11)
   44 (1,2,4,11,22)
   55 (1,5,11)
   66 (1,2,3,6,11,22,33)
   77 (1,7,11)
   88 (1,2,4,8,11,22,44)
   99 (1,3,9,11,33)
   121 (1,11)
   202 (1,2,101)
```

and below is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Palindrome 
{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int e = 0;
        int pal = 0;
        int start = 10;
        int end = 10000;
        for(int i = start; i<=end; i+=1)
        {
               if(isPalindrome(i))
               {
                  pal = i;
                  System.out.println(pal + " " + getDivisors(pal));


               }


        }

    }

    public static ArrayList getDivisors (int number)
    {
        ArrayList numbersDivisor = new ArrayList();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= number; i++ )
        {
            if (number%i == 0 && i != number && isPalindrome(i))
            {
                numbersDivisor.add(i);
            }
        }
        return numbersDivisor;
    }

    public static int properDivisors(int a)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <=a; i++)
        {
            if (a%i == 0 && i !=a)
            {
                return i;  

            }

        }
        return i;

    }


    public static boolean isPalindrome (int a)
    {
        int reversedNumber = reverse(a);
        String orgNumber = Integer.toString(a);
        String oppNumber = Integer.toString(reversedNumber);
        if(oppNumber.equals(orgNumber))
        {
            return true;

        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    static int reverse(int a) 
    {
        int number = a;
        int reverse = 0;
        while (number != 0)
        {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + number%10;
        number = number/10;
        }
        return reverse;
    }


}
```

Comment: "those palindromic numbers that are also palindromic" ???

Comment: I ran your program and its giving correct output. `1` itself is palindrome and it divides all the numbers, so your output looks correct. Am I missing here something?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that the program needs to print only palindromic numbers whose proper divisors are also palindromic. so, for example " 9999 [1, 3, 9, 11, 33, 99, 101, 303, 909, 1111, 3333]" The number 9999 is a palindrome and ALL of its proper divisors are also palindromic. The program must exclude any number that is not palindromic and if it is palindromic then all of its proper divisors also need to be palindromic.

Comment: @MarioHernandez Sorry I missed the part of `Prime Numbers`. That said your `Palindrom` number shouldn't be `prime`. Then all you have to check is, before printing your number is prime or not. So make a method for checking the prime numbers and put a condition before printing that number ans divisors

Answer (score 0):

Your program looks quite thorough and good. It needs small tweaks.

In your main method you need to make following changes inside the for loop

```
List al = new ArrayList();
if (isPalindrome(i) && areAllDivisorsPalindromic(i, al))
{ ... }
```

areAllDivisorsPalindromic() is replacing getDivisors() method. Its just a method renaming because we are adding a different capability. It will have the same logic of getDivisors() but needs a small tweak.

```
boolean allDivisorsPalindromes = true
if(i% number ==0 && i!=number && !isPalindrome(number)){
     allDivisorsPalindromes = false;
    return allDivisorsPalindromes ;
}else{
    // add the number to the arrayList
}
return allDivisorsPalindromes
```

the key concept used is that of Short circuit feature.

In addition, I believe you should replace the following condition

```
i!=number
```

in areAllDivisorsPalindromic()  to

```
 i = number
```

because number may be a prime number.

Comment: Thanks! I understand what you are saying. I will try to implement it right now.

Comment: Sorry I think I have a slight misunderstanding. The new areAllDivisorsPalindromic method, is it still an ArrayList or boolean?

Comment: It will return a boolean value -- allDivisorsPalindromes Whatever changes you do to ArrayList in areAllDivisorsPalindromic () will be available for Sysout in main()

Comment: Sorry If this is totally going over my head but, should the new method be "public static boolean areAllDivisorsPalindromic (int number, List al)"? so it should have two constructors? and it will have an ArrayList variable in it? And it also cannot be a prime number so it should remain !=.

Comment: I am sorry if I am confusing you. Yes the new method will be exactly as you wrote. I do not know why you are saying constructors. Your arraylist construction will happen only in main method. And you need to pass arraylist to it.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my previous comments. You need to check for Prime number, if palindrome number is prime then don't print that number.

Currently your printing all the palindrome numbers which are also prime, which you don't need. Just to note, Prime numbers will return array list of 1 only, which you can avoid by following.

Here is quick fix for you.

```
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i += 1) {
        if (isPalindrome(i)) {
            pal = i;
            if (!isPrime(i)) // Check for Prime Palindrome number
                System.out.println(pal + " " + getDivisors(pal));
        }
    }

// Prime number checker method

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    // check if n is a multiple of 2
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    // if not, then just check the odds
    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Note:** There is only one problem left with your code to get correct output, but I leave that part for you to figure out. Good Luck.

Comment: You're right I do only need prime numbers! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MarioHernandez No you **only** need the numbers which are `palindrome` and `not prime`. Good Luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `getDivisors` function, by a method returning true if your number contains only palindromic divisors, and false is there one or more non palindromic divisors:

```
public static boolean areOnlyPalindromicDivisors(int number) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < number; i++ ) {
        if (number%i == 0) {
            if(!isPalindrome(i))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you want to get all divisors, you can adapt the previous code like this:

```
if(isPalindrome(i)) {
     numbersDivisor.add(i);
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Of course, you need to filter the output of this function to handle the `null` cases, which mean that there is at least one non-palindromic divisor.